# manage sibling li elements from span in jQuery

Tags: jquery

here is my html ( all li and span comes dynamically )

```
<div id="VMScrollBoth1" class="sliderGallery">
        <ul>
            <li class="VMScrollBoth handle6"><span><a href="#"><img src="imagex.png"></a></span></li>
            <li class="VMScrollBoth handle6"><span><a href="#"><img src="imagex2.png"></a></span></li>
            <li class="VMScrollBoth handle6"><span><a href="#"><img src="imagex3.png"></a></span></li>
            <li class="VMScrollBoth handle7"><span><a href="#"><img src="imagex4.png"></a></span></li>
            <li class="VMScrollBoth handle7"><span><a href="#"><img src="imagex5.png"></a></span></li>
            <li class="VMScrollBoth handle8"><span><a href="#"><img src="imagex6.png"></a></span></li>
            <li class="VMScrollBoth handle8"><span><a href="#"><img src="imagex7.png"></a></span></li>
            <li class="VMScrollBoth handle8"><span><a href="#"><img src="imagex.png"></a></span></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="slider ui-slider">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)"> <div class="handle"></div></a>
            <span class="slider-lbl1" id="handle8">SIENNA</span>
            <span class="slider-lbl1" id="handle6">CARRIE</span>
            <span class="slider-lbl1" id="handle7">ISABELLE</span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

what i want is . On page load all li elements shoud be display but when i click on span having id `handle8` then only that li element would be display which have class `handle8`, rest of all li elements shoud be hidden

i write below code:

```
<style>
.gayab {display:none }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
 jQuery('.slider-lbl1').live('click',function () { 
      var catID = jQuery(this).attr('id');
      console.log(catID);
      jQuery(this).parent().parent().children('ul').children('li').filter(
         function(index) { 
             if((jQuery(this).hasClass(catID))){
                   jQuery(this).removeClass('gayab');
           } else {
                   jQuery(this).addClass('gayab');
           }
        })
     })
</script>
```

it's working fine on FF but not working in IE ( i have IE7), please first optimize my code, i know this is very complex way to use jQuery & also tell me how to fix ot in IE
Thanks
**UPDATE:** `VMScrollBoth1` is also coming dynamicaly, it can be `VMScrollBoth2` or `VMScrollBoth99`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can shorten it down to this:

```
jQuery('.slider-lbl1').live('click',function () {
  $("#VMScrollBoth1 li:not(." + this.id +")").hide();
})​;​
```

[You can give it a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/6A8hN/), this takes the clicked element's `id`, and finds any `<li>` elements under `#VMScrollBoth1` that do [`:not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) have that [`.class`](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/), and [`.hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/)s them.

[`.hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/)/[`.show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/) are easier methods than having a class just for `display: none;` :)

Here's also a version that works for future clicks:

```
jQuery('.slider-lbl1').live('click',function () {
  $("#VMScrollBoth1 li").show().not("." + this.id).hide();
});​
```

This shows all the `<li>` elements then filters again on each click, allowing you to click multiple handles and the visible list updates each time, [you can try it here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/6A8hN/2/).

Comment: but we have have to show that are hidden due o previous click? and whoud we use `this.id` or `this.attr('id')`

Comment: @JustLearn - I added a version for this, try the bottom version :)

Comment: how do i know the result?? there is no image at all in ur example?

Comment: @JustLearn - I don't have your images, I updated with a version of dummy images though: http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/6A8hN/2/

Comment: @Thanksssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss

Answer (score 0):

Two quick points (I'd write a comment instead of an answer, but I can't yet do that):

1. "console" breaks your IE7 javascript,
2. in case you copied your code into your question as is, ".gayab {di**a**play:none }" has a typo in it, di**A**play instead of di**S**play.

...but see the other answers instead. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an easier way to do, and safer as it does not use relative paths:

```
jQuery('.slider-lbl1').live('click',function () {
    var handle = this.id;
    $('.VMScrollBoth').each(function() {
        $(this).toggle($(this).hasClass(handle));
    });
});
```

Comment: `<li>` elements aren't by default `block` :)

Comment: @Nick: You're right, I edited my answer to use the hide and show functions instead of changing the CSS display attribute.

Comment: There's also a `.toggle(bool)` ;) As an aside, use `this.id`, there's no need for all that extra code to get a DOM property :)